# MOD10 Credit card validation

Tags: java, validation, credit-card

- Step 1: Double the value of alternate digits of the card number beginning with the second digit from the right.
- Step 2: Add the individual digits obtained in Step 1 and each of the unaffected digits in the original number.
- Step 3: If the total obtained in Step 2 is divisible by 10, the card number is valid, otherwise, it is invalid.

E.g. to validate the card number of a VISA card 49977393716 by using Mod 10 algorithm:

Step 1:

```
4 9 9 7 7 3 9 3 7 1 6
  x2  x2  x2  x2  x2

= 18 14 6 6 2
```

Step 2: `4 + (1+8) + 9 + (1+4) + 7 + (6) + 9 + (6) + 7 + (2) + 6 = 70`

Step 3: 70 is divisible by 10 ⇒ the card number is valid

This is the second part to a question. So I got the cardnumber userInput as a String. Does that mean I have to charAt(), the wanted characters//alternate values.

```
     int[] digits = new int[cardNo.length()/2];//Number of alternate values available
        char digit1;
        char digit2;
        int intDigit1;
        int intDigit2;
        int[] sumOfTwoDigits = new int[cardNo.length()/2];
        int totalSum;
        String digitsChar;

 for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){             
            digits[i]=(cardNo.charAt(i+1))*2; 
            digitsChar=Integer.toString(digits[i]);
            digit1= digitsChar.charAt(1);
            digit2= digitsChar.charAt(2);
            intDigit1= Character.getNumericValue(digit1);//Convert char to int to perform addition
            intDigit2= Character.getNumericValue(digit2);//Convert char to int to perform addition

            sumOfTwoDigits[i] = intDigit1+intDigit2;
            System.out.println("digits: " + intDigit1);

        }
```

Comment: they run but somewhere in the logic is wrong. i get 0 for every iteration

Comment: What language is this? @leppie This is not javascript.

Comment: @some: Oops, did not notice the `System.out.println` ;p So java!

Comment: Oh I didn't know this was the algorithm, so `00000000000` is a valid CC number?

Comment: @dualed Technically, 00000000000 is valid since it has the right checksum. However I wouldn't be surprised if it is excluded somewhere in the the standard. It is often used to indicate that no number is entered. Therefore there will never ever be an account attached to that card number. Remember that the purpose of the Luhn-algorithm is to detect if the number is entered incorrectly. To verify if the card is valid you must check online with the card issuer.

Comment: @some Hm, I just expected the algorithm to be different so that patterns like `050505050505` would not be possible.

Comment: Is this your actual code, and it usually works ok? You write `digits[i]=(cardNo.charAt(i+1))*2;`, so you don't take alternating numbers, and you don't take the numeric value of the char, you take its int representation (if you debug your example, you will see that this line of code leaves digits[0] to be 114, because the int representation of the char '9' happens to be 57)

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- you should start from the right *end* of the sequence of digits and work to the left. The last digit in a credit card number if the check digit.  Some credit cards have an odd number of digits others have an even number of digits. Starting from the 'right' end of the string is one way to ensure that you're doubling the correct digits.
- the fact that some credit cards use an odd number of digits means you can't rely on being able to handle two characters in each loop (at least not without special case handling for that odd, leftover character).
- when you double a digit, if you end up with a result that's greater than 10 you want to subtract 9 from the result (effectively adding the two digits together) before folding it into the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

My java is a little rusty, but here we go:

```
public static boolean luhnVerify(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  int value;
  int idx = str.length(); // Start from the end of string
  boolean alt = false;

  while(idx-- > 0) {
    // Get value. Throws error if it isn't a digit
    value = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(idx, idx + 1));
    if (alt) {
      value *= 2;
      if (value > 9) value -= 9;
    }
    sum += value;
    alt = !alt;  //Toggle alt-flag
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
```

The [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) starts from the right end, then multiply every other digit with 2 and add the result.

1. In the code above I use `Integer.parseInt(str.substring(idx,idx+1))` to get each digit from the string. If it isn't a digit an error will be thrown.
2. There I check the `alt`-flag and if it is true I multiply the value by 2. If the result is larger than 9 I subtract 9. That gives the same result as adding 1+[0-8].
3. I add the value to the sum and toggle the `alt`-flag.
4. The result is true if the sum is even divisible by 10.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to write code that does what I guess yours intend:

```
String cardNo = "49977393716";
int[] digits = new int[cardNo.length()/2]; //Number of alternate values available
int[] sumOfTwoDigits = new int[cardNo.length()/2];

for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){ 
        //get the numeric value of the char, instead of the int representation            
        digits[i]=Character.getNumericValue(cardNo.charAt(2*i+1))*2;

        //using Michael Burr's trick
        sumOfTwoDigits[i] = digits[i] >= 10 ? digits[i] - 9 : digits[i]; 
}
```

You ran into trouble because you assigned a `char` to a position in an `int[]`, and thus used the int representation of the `char`. Because of this, calls to `digitsChar[2]` did not fail (which it always should, as the double of any digit never can have more than two digits, and half of them have only one), because double the `int` representation of the digit `char`s all have three digits.